# Script cannot find file

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, launch

I am trying to run a script named `myscript.command` on a Mac/Linux machine.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Starting'
chmod 777 ./myfile
```

The problem is that when I get to the `chmod` part I get this output:

```
chmod ./myfile: No such file or directory
```

But both `myscript.command` and the `myfile` are in the same folder.

**EDIT**

It seems that when I launch the script the script's location is not being preserved. How can I preserve the location?

The script is being launched via double click in the UI.

Comment: Is the file there?

Comment: Yes, the file is there.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you also shared the output of "ls -l" from that directory. Note that the script will be indifferent to which directory you start it from... but will check the "current" directory for the file.

Comment: It looks like `./` is not giving me the folder I am currently in but the root directory of my computer.

Comment: How exactly are you running `myscript.command`, from the current directory as `./myscript.command`, or something like `bash /path/to/myscript.command`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov After I renamed my `.sh` file to `.command` I just double click it and it opens up in my terminal. In the script I might have to add a line that tells the script to run in the directory that it is in?

Comment: @J_Strauton, try to put `pwd` command into the script to check if the launcher preserved location

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov `pwd` shows that it did not preserve location. How can I make the script preserve the location?

Comment: @J_Strauton, `cd $(dirname "$0")`, or `chmod 777 "$(dirname "$0")"/myfile`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov that got very close but the `cd` part is telling me that `: cd: /Users/me/Desktop/ScriptDirectory: No such file or directory`

Comment: @J_Strauton, try to use double quotes: `cd "$(dirname "$0")"`

Comment: What directory are these scripts in, and where is `myfile`?

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You absolutely do not want to grant write access to executable or system files to all users under any circumstances. You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and learn about the Unix permissions model before you try to use it again. If this happened on a system with Internet access, check whether an intruder could have exploited this to escalate their privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**$0**

In order to change the current working directory to the script's directory, put the following command right after the shebang line:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

The `$0` variable expands to the script name (path to the script), and `dirname` returns path to the script's directory.

**Detecting the current working directory**

You can use `pwd` command to get the current working directory. If you are actually running Bash (I'm not sure, since the shebang in your code points to `/bin/sh`), you can use the built-in `$PWD` variable:

> `PWD`
>        The current working directory as set by the `cd` builtin.

**Storing the script's path into variable**

Alternatively, save the directory path into a variable, and use it in the script, e.g.:

```
dir="$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd)"
chmod 770 "$dir/somefile"
```

**Double quotes**

Note the use of double quotes. Double quotes prevent reinterpretation of special characters. It is also the way to pass strings containing spaces as a single word:

```
dir="some directory name"
cd "$dir"
```

Without double quotes the words are interpreted as separate arguments.

Answer (score -1):

You might start off something like this, too..

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Starting'
if [ -f ./myfile ]; then
  chmod 777 ./myfile
else
  echo "File does not exist:"
  ls -l
fi
```